# how to remove span tag from smarty value in htm file?

Tags: php, smarty

I have htm file called user.htm. Here i will display my user details.When i'm trying to add link to user image i have one problem. span tag is exist in the image link.

For ex, 
$img_link= '/image/users/44.jpg'.I want to remove the span tag from $img_link in user.htm.

my code is:

```
<img src="http://www.mysite.com/Imprenta/{$ruta_value}" height="50px" width="150px" />
```

Here the value of {$ruta_value} is => '/user/images/44.jpg'

I can not use PHP functions like str_replace or strip_tags here. how to do it?

Comment: sorry.. my value is like this. $img_link= '<span>/image/users/44.jpg</span>'

Comment: Can you show some real codes please ...

Comment: @jeeva you are doing all wrong, how are you using smarty variable inside php tags??

Comment: yes. i'm sorry. now i corrected it.

Answer (score 3):

You can very much use **[strip_tags](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.strip.tags.tpl)** in smarty like this ,

```
{$img_link|strip_tags}
```

So in your case, it will be like

```
<img src="http://www.mysite.com/Imprenta/{$ruta_value|strip_tags}" height="50px" width="150px" />
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove span tag from HTML give it an ID `<span id="userSpan"> </span>`
then use little JavaScript here

```
var span = document.getElementById("userSpan");
span.parentNode.removeChild(span);
```